# Change position of the caption with the all lstlisting

Tags: captions, listings

I have a problem with the position of the caption with the `lstlisting`.

This is a minimal example

```
\documentclass[12pt]{toptesi}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

% INCLUSIONE PACCHETTI
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} %utf8
\usepackage[italian]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{graphicx,wrapfig}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{varioref}
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{paralist}{\obeyspaces\global\let =\space}
\usepackage{verbatim}
\usepackage{subfig}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage[pass]{geometry}
\usepackage[figuresright]{rotating}
\usepackage{algorithm}
\usepackage{algorithmic}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[babel]{csquotes}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage[backend=bibtex]{biblatex}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{titlesec}

% CONFIGURAZIONE LISTATI/CODICE
\definecolor{commentgreen}{RGB}{2,112,10}
\definecolor{eminence}{RGB}{108,48,130}
\definecolor{weborange}{RGB}{255,165,0}
\definecolor{frenchplum}{RGB}{129,20,83}

\lstset {
    language=C++,
    frame=tb,
    tabsize=4,
    showstringspaces=false,
    numbers=left,
    %upquote=true,
    commentstyle=\color{commentgreen},
    keywordstyle=\color{eminence},
    stringstyle=\color{red},
    basicstyle=\small\ttfamily, % basic font setting
    emph={int,char,double,float,unsigned,void,bool},
    emphstyle={\color{blue}},
    escapechar=\&,
    % keyword highlighting
    classoffset=1, % starting new class
    otherkeywords={>,<,.,;,-,!,=,~},
    morekeywords={>,<,.,;,-,!,=,~},
    keywordstyle=\color{weborange},
    classoffset=0,
}

% definizione BITCOIN script
\lstdefinelanguage{bitcoinscript}{
    alsodigit = {-},
    keywords = {OP_DUP,OP_HASH160,OP_EQUALVERIFY,OP_CHECKSIG, OP_CHECKMULTISIG,
                OP_0, OP_2, OP_3, OP_EQUAL},
}

%Definizione MINISCRIPT
\lstdefinelanguage{miniscript}{
    keywords = {thresh,pk,older},
}

\begin{document}

\begin{lstlisting}[label={code:enumtx}, caption={Porzione di codice che riporta il tipo enumerazione nel file standard.h di bitcoin core.}]

enum txnouttype
{
    TX_NONSTANDARD,
    TX_PUBKEY,
    TX_PUBKEYHASH,
    TX_SCRIPTHASH,
    TX_MULTISIG,
    TX_NULL_DATA, //!< unspendable OP_RETURN script that carries data
    TX_WITNESS_V0_SCRIPTHASH,
    TX_WITNESS_V0_KEYHASH,
    TX_WITNESS_UNKNOWN, //!< Only for Witness versions not already defined above
};
\end{lstlisting}

\end{document}
```

This is the result

[image]

In this result, I have 2 problems,

1. The line 1 is overflow
2. the caption in the top position but I want it in the button position

Comment: Could you please edit your code to include a complete compilable [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) that includes the documentclass, as well as the *relevant* packages. Currently, your preamble snippet is filled with a bunch of unrelate packages. Also, the file `exampleComplexNoMiniscript.btcs` is not available to us.

Comment: `captionpos=b` might help to place the caption below the listing instead of above while `breaklines=true` might help to prevent to overflowing line.

Comment: @leandriis I have updated my question, sorry my superficiality

Comment: @leandriis your solution works well thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `captionpos=b`  to place the caption below the listing instead of above while `breaklines=true` hleps to avoid overflowing lines by allowing linebreaks:

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt]{toptesi}

\usepackage{subfig}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage[pass]{geometry}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\definecolor{commentgreen}{RGB}{2,112,10}
\definecolor{eminence}{RGB}{108,48,130}
\definecolor{weborange}{RGB}{255,165,0}

\lstset {
    language=C++,
    frame=tb,
    tabsize=4,
    showstringspaces=false,
    numbers=left,
    %upquote=true,
    commentstyle=\color{commentgreen},
    keywordstyle=\color{eminence},
    stringstyle=\color{red},
    basicstyle=\small\ttfamily, % basic font setting
    emph={int,char,double,float,unsigned,void,bool},
    emphstyle={\color{blue}},
    escapechar=\&,
    % keyword highlighting
    classoffset=1, % starting new class
    otherkeywords={>,<,.,;,-,!,=,~},
    morekeywords={>,<,.,;,-,!,=,~},
    keywordstyle=\color{weborange},
    classoffset=0,
    captionpos=b,
    breaklines=true
}


\begin{document}

\begin{lstlisting}[label={code:enumtx}, caption={Porzione di codice che riporta il tipo enumerazione nel file standard.h di bitcoin core.}]

enum txnouttype
{
    TX_NONSTANDARD,
    TX_PUBKEY,
    TX_PUBKEYHASH,
    TX_SCRIPTHASH,
    TX_MULTISIG,
    TX_NULL_DATA, //!< unspendable OP_RETURN script that carries data
    TX_WITNESS_V0_SCRIPTHASH,
    TX_WITNESS_V0_KEYHASH,
    TX_WITNESS_UNKNOWN, //!< Only for Witness versions not already defined above
};
\end{lstlisting}

\end{document}
```